# Navigation Bar through Bootstrap. How to get the components of the NavBar on the right rather than left in mobile or tablet mode?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

[image: Reference image]

How do we put the list on the right side of the screen, just under the toggle or hamburger icon?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following CSS:

```
#nav-link active{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: right;
}
```

This should align all the elements in your "navbar-nav ml-auto" div to the right side.

Comment: ok!..so this will display the elements under the toggle ,right???

Comment: Correct. This will apply only to the "#nav-link active" div.